# Strange hyphenation behaviour with multirow, plus problems with hyphenating german-language words with umlauts

Tags: tabularx, hyphenation, multirow, german, ragged2e

I have problems with hyphenation in multirow text cells, again. In some cases, this totally gets ignored even though using hyphenation.

Bonus question would be, how do I tell \hyphenation to hyphenate "ß", since its Latex code \ss{} is not allowed as an argument. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}


\hyphenation{Ein-fluss-gr\"o-\ss en}
\hyphenation{So-zio-\"oko-no-mische}
\hyphenation{An-ge-bots-spe-zi-fi-sche}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb] 
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{5.1em}|P{19.2em}|}

\hline
\multirow{7}{3.6em}
{\hspace{0pt}Demographische Einflussgrößen} & Alter \\*
 & Geschlecht \\*
 & Erwerbstätigkeit \\*
 & Schulbildung \\*
 & Einschränkung der Mobilität \\*
 & Einschränkung der Sinne \\*
 & Sprachbarrieren \\\hline

\multirow{4}{3.6em}
{\hspace{0pt}Sozioökonomische} & Beruf\\*
 & Einkommen \\*
 & Haushaltsstruktur \\*
 & Pkw-Verfügbarkeit \\\hline

\multirow{9}{3.6em}
{\hspace{0pt}Psychologische Einflussgrößen} & Motive \\*
 & Wertvorstellungen \\*
 & Lern- und Gewöhnungseffekte \\*
 & Kognitive Prozesse \\*
 & Kenntnis des Ortes \\*
 & Kenntnis des Systems \\* 
 & Image des Verkehrsmittels \\*
 & Subjektive Produktpräferenzen \\*
 & \hangindent=1em Einstellung zu angebotsspezifischen Einflussgrößen \\\hline

\multirow{2}{3.6em}
{\hspace{0pt}Angebotsspezifische}
 & Verfügbarkeit der Verkehrsmittel \\*
 & \hangindent=1em Zur Verfügung stehende Informationen \\\hline

 \multirow{5}{3.6em}
 {\hspace{0pt}Situationsspezifische Einflussgrößen}  & Gepäcktransport \\*
 & Fahrradmitnahme \\*
 & Tageszeit \\*
 & Jahreszeit \\*
 & Wetter \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Einflussgrößen}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any chance you could switch to LuaLaTeX? The reason I ask is that LuaLaTeX, unlike pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX, has no problems hyphenating the first word of a (logical) paragraph.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means for the rest of my document, thus I'd rather refrain from trying it - especially 1 week before my thesis' deadline.

Comment: A simple solution would be to simply hard-code the breaks, like so: `Sozio\"oko- nomische` (note the space after the hyphen). I do this often when not satisfied with LaTeX's line-breaking in tables. Also maybe try `\raggedright` instead of `\RaggedRight`.

Comment: I tried \hspace{0pt}Sozioöko\- \mbox{nomische} Einfluss\- größen, but then "nomische" is too wide for the cell leading to an arbitrary vskip for whatever reason. Any way to get rid of this? Simply substracting vspace doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a weird (read: unfortunate) interaction between the `multirow`, `tabularx`, and `ragged2e` packages. I suggest you ditch the `multirow` machinery entirely and use side-by-side `tabular` environments in the two columns of the `tabularx` environment.

In the following screenshot, you will immediately notice the difference in linespacing between the left-hand and right-hand columns. That's because of the instruction `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` that's in your code and which I didn't remove. You should probably remove this instruction or, at least, modify it to something like `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\hyphenation{an-ge-bots-spe-zi-fi-sche}

\newlength\mylength
\setlength{\mylength}{3.6em} % set usable width of first column
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb] 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{\mylength}|x|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}P{\mylength}@{}}
  Demographische Einflussgrößen 
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Alter \\
  Geschlecht \\
  Erwerbstätigkeit \\
  Schulbildung \\
  Einschränkung der Mobilität \\
  Einschränkung der Sinne \\
  Sprachbarrieren 
\end{tabular}\\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}P{\mylength}@{}}    
  Sozioökonomische
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}  
  Beruf\\
  Einkommen \\
  Haushaltsstruktur \\
  Pkw-Verfügbarkeit 
\end{tabular}\\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}P{\mylength}@{}}    
  Psychologische Einflussgrößen
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}    
  Motive \\
  Wertvorstellungen \\
  Lern- und Gewöhnungseffekte \\
  Kognitive Prozesse \\
  Kenntnis des Ortes \\
  Kenntnis des Systems \\ 
  Image des Verkehrsmittels \\
  Subjektive Produktpräferenzen \\ 
  Einstellung zu angebotsspezifischen Einflussgrößen 
\end{tabular}\\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}P{\mylength}@{}}    
  Angebotsspezifische
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}    
  Verfügbarkeit der Verkehrsmittel \\
  Zur Verfügung stehende Informationen
\end{tabular}\\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}P{\mylength}@{}}    
  Situationsspezifische Einflussgrößen
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}      
  Gepäcktransport \\
  Fahrradmitnahme \\
  Tageszeit \\
  Jahreszeit \\
  Wetter 
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Einflussgrößen}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, I set the (usable) width of the first column of the `tabularx` environment to `3.6em` simply because that's what you were doing in your code. Speaking for myself, I think it would be more desirable to set the width to ca. `5em`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a different way from what I'd have considered. I might give it a try, when my ugly workaround "\hspace{0pt}Sozioöko\- \mbox{nomische} Einfluss\- größen" doesn't work. Any idea for how to avoid the vertical skip before "nomische" (overfull cell width, even though not looking like it)?

Comment: @D.Duesen - Yes: just remove the two instances of whitespace after `\-`. Note that you can also dispense with `\hspace{0pt}` and the `\mbox` wrapper. Thus, just write `Sozioöko\-nomische Einfluss\-größen`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well! Do you know how to align these cell entries vertically? Using an "m" column does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: @D.Duesen - Please clarify what you mean by "align these cell entries vertically".

Comment: I might be in need of a new question, since I can't post a picture here. But I was referring to the vertical alignment which can be seen in my initial picture as well: the second and fourth entry in the left column are slightly below, the third one slightly above the tabular cell's centre.

Comment: Seems to be a multirow problem, since it afflects only those entries with more lines needed than specified in the multirow commando.

Comment: @D.Duesen - The robustness of the `multirow` package is known to be less than perfect. That's why, in part, I chose to provide an answer that doesn't involve `multirow` at all.

Comment: I would have loved to implement your solution, but that did not work - possibly due to the third column I wasn't mentioning here. Might you take a look on my new question dealing with that problem in a more detailed way? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360172/odd-vertical-alignment-of-multirow-cells Thank you anyways!