# Odd vertical alignment of multirow cells

Tags: vertical-alignment, multirow

Another multirow (v2.1) problem I cannot get rid of: Why are the cell entries in the first column aligned vertically in such an odd way? Is there a way to change that? Does not have to be a beautiful solution due to restraints in time. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\RaggedRight}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp] 
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{5.1em}|P{15em}|P{19.2em}|}

\hline
\multirow{7}{5.1em}
{Demogra\-phische Einfluss\-größen} & Alter & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*
 & Geschlecht & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*
 & Erwerbstätigkeit & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*
 & Schulbildung & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*
 & Einschränkung der Mobilität & wesentlich\\*
 & Einschränkung der Sinne & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\*
 & Sprachbarrieren & wesentlich\\\hline

\multirow{4}{5.1em}
{Sozioöko\-nomische Einfluss\-größen} & Beruf & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*

 & Einkommen & irrelevant aufgrund von Fahrgastrechten\\*
 & Haushaltsstruktur & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*
 & Pkw-Verfügbarkeit & wesentlich für Maßnahmen vor Fahrtbeginn\\\hline

\multirow{9}{5.1em}
{\hspace{0pt}Psychologische Einfluss\-größen} & Motive & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung \small\textsuperscript{a)}\\*
 & Wertvorstellungen & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung \small\textsuperscript{a)}\\*
 & Lern- und Gewöhnungseffekte & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung \small\textsuperscript{b)}\\*
 & Kognitive Prozesse & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung \small\textsuperscript{b)}\\*
 & Kenntnis des Ortes & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\*
 & Kenntnis des Systems & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\* 
 & Image des Verkehrsmittels & irrelevant aufgrund der Notsituation\\*
 & Subjektive Produktpräferenzen & irrelevant aufgrund der Notsituation\\*
 & \hangindent=1em Einstellung zu angebotsspezifischen Einflussgrößen & \hangindent=1em im Rahmen der Modellierung der Widerstandskomponenten abgedeckt (Kapitel \ref{Vergleichbarmachung})\\\hline

\multirow{5}{5.1em}
{Angebots\-spezifische Einfluss\-größen} & \hangindent=1em Umgang mit demographischen Einschränkungen & wesentlich\\*
 & Verfügbarkeit der Verkehrsmittel & irrelevant aufgrund der Notsituation\\*
 & \hangindent=1em Zur Verfügung stehende Informationen & wesentlich\\\hline

 \multirow{5}{5.1em}
 {Situations\-spezifische Einfluss\-größen}  & Gepäcktransport & wesentlich\\*
 & Fahrradmitnahme & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\*
 & Tageszeit & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\*
 & Jahreszeit & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\*
 & Wetter & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the LaTeX document class `tudthesis` available online somewhere? Does the problem persist if you replace `tudthesis` by, say, `article` or `report`? If so, the problem wouldn't appear to be caused by the document class -- in which case you may want to use a more generic document class for your MWE.

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally forgot to exchange that. Problem is, article is leading to further problems I have to get rid of before editing my initial post...

Comment: Namely, every text cell begins with - 6- 24.3em, as if article could not cope with me substracting tabcolseps in the column width declaration. Report doesn't work as well.

Comment: I succeeded exchanging documentclass by specifying fixed column widths. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Does loading the `calc` package help?

Comment: If you use fixed column widths, you probably shouldn't be using a `tabularx` environment, right?

Comment: @Mico I really should make that an error, I think. (although it seems it would break a lot of documents. maybe just a warning) although I think I saw someone (you?) cunningly using no X in the main preamble and adding them via `\multicolumn`...

Comment: @Mico Loading package calc does not help. Using a tabular environment doesn't, either.

Comment: @Mico: Might nested tabulars, as you pointed them out as a respond to my last question, work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using `\multirow` for the items in the first column. When using `\multirow` and the objective is to center the item vertically w.r.t. the material in the next column, it's important to set the first argument of `\multirow` to the total number of rows in the column to the right.

The code below uses a `tabularx` environment, but it uses relative rather than absolute widths for columns 2 and 3. David Carlisle would approve. :-)

A final comment: I'd like to challenge you to rethink the need for engaging in vertical centering at all. Even if you don't place the items in the first column in `\multirow` wrappers, it will be perfectly clear to your readers how the material in the three columns hangs together.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % sorry, I don't have the "tudthesis" class

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,ragged2e}
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\RaggedRight}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hangindent=1em}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}       % default value: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1} % 1.35 seems wildly excessive...

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{5.1em}|>{\hsize=0.85\hsize}Y|>{\hsize=1.15\hsize}Y|}
\hline
\multirow{7}{=}{Demogra\-phische Einfluss\-größen} 
 & Alter & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*
 & Geschlecht & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*
 & Erwerbstätigkeit & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*
 & Schulbildung & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*
 & Einschränkung der Mobilität & wesentlich\\*
 & Einschränkung der Sinne & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\*
 & Sprachbarrieren & wesentlich\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{=}{Sozioöko\-nomische Einfluss\-größen} 
 & Beruf & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*
 & Einkommen & irrelevant aufgrund von Fahrgastrechten\\*
 & Haushaltsstruktur & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\*
 & Pkw-Verfügbarkeit & wesentlich für Maßnahmen vor Fahrtbeginn\\
\hline
\multirow{10}{=}{Psycho\-logische Einfluss\-größen} 
 & Motive & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung \small\textsuperscript{a)}\\*
 & Wertvorstellungen & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung \small\textsuperscript{a)}\\*
 & Lern- und Gewöhnungseffekte & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung \small\textsuperscript{b)}\\*
 & Kognitive Prozesse & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung \small\textsuperscript{b)}\\*
 & Kenntnis des Ortes & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\*
 & Kenntnis des Systems & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\*
 & Image des Verkehrsmittels & irrelevant aufgrund der Notsituation\\*
 & Subjektive Produktpräferenzen & irrelevant aufgrund der Notsituation\\*
 & Einstellung zu angebotsspezifischen Einflussgrößen & im Rahmen der Modellierung der Widerstandskomponenten abgedeckt (Kapitel \ref{Vergleichbarmachung})\\
\hline
\multirow{5}{=}{Angebots\-spezifische Einfluss\-größen} 
 & Umgang mit demographischen Einschränkungen & wesentlich\\*
 & Verfügbarkeit der Verkehrsmittel & irrelevant aufgrund der Notsituation\\*
 & Zur Verfügung stehende Informationen & wesentlich\\
\hline
\multirow{5}{=}{Situations\-spezifische Einfluss\-größen}  
 & Gepäcktransport & wesentlich\\*
 & Fahrradmitnahme & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\*
 & Tageszeit & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\*
 & Jahreszeit & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\*
 & Wetter & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With recent `multirow` you can instead of `\multirow{...}{5.1em}{ ...}`  use new option `=`:  `\multirow{...}{=}{ ...}`. What is function of asterix after `\\ `, i.e.: `\\*` ?

Comment: @Zarko - About the asterisk: I have no idea; you better ask the OP. About the `=` sign: a great suggestion! I'll edit the code right away.

Comment: That code as it is, doesn't fix the oddity of the first columns (like the op mentioned in the question)

Comment: @doed - What do you mean? AFAICT, the contents of the cells in the first column are not centered vertically.

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, the asterisk came from constructing this as a longtable first. Doesn't hurt here, I guess?

Comment: @Mico Your code works for not stretching the array too much (or would work for {\arraystretch}{2}). For {\arraystretch}{1.35}, the number for the second-to-last multirow would have to be in between 4 (slightly above the cell's centre) and 5 (slightly below the cell's centre). Unfortunately, that's no valid argument for \multirow.

Comment: @Mico Even though I don't consider {\arraystretch}{1.35} to be "wildly excessive", I changed it to 1.1 as suggested by you. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @D.Duesen - Glad I as able to help. Indeed, the requirement that the first argument of `\multirow` has to be integer-valued is, in my view, one of its shortcomings.

Answer (score 5):

Not a solution to the `\multirow` problem, but the proposal of a different layout for your table, that is, with *titles*.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 \hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp] 
\centering

\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}P{0.80}P{1.20}@{}}
\toprule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape Demographische Einflussgrößen} \\
\addlinespace
Alter & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\
Geschlecht & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\
Erwerbstätigkeit & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\
Schulbildung & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\
Einschränkung der Mobilität & wesentlich\\
Einschränkung der Sinne & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\
Sprachbarrieren & wesentlich\\
\midrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape Sozioökonomische Einflussgrößen} \\
\addlinespace
Beruf & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\
Einkommen & irrelevant aufgrund von Fahrgastrechten\\
Haushaltsstruktur & kein direkter Einfluss erkennbar\\
Pkw-Verfügbarkeit & wesentlich für Maßnahmen vor Fahrtbeginn\\
\midrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape Psychologische Einflussgrößen} \\
\addlinespace
Motive & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung\textsuperscript{a)}\\
Wertvorstellungen & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung\textsuperscript{a)}\\
Lern- und Gewöhnungseffekte & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung\textsuperscript{b)}\\
Kognitive Prozesse & zu wenig greifbar für die Modellierung\textsuperscript{b)}\\
Kenntnis des Ortes & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\
Kenntnis des Systems & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\ 
Image des Verkehrsmittels & irrelevant aufgrund der Notsituation\\
Subjektive Produktpräferenzen & irrelevant aufgrund der Notsituation\\
Einstellung zu angebotsspezifischen Einflussgrößen &
   im Rahmen der Modellierung der Widerstandskomponenten abgedeckt (Kapitel \ref{Vergleichbarmachung})\\
\midrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape Angebotsspezifische Einflussgrößen} \\
\addlinespace
Umgang mit demographischen Einschränkungen & wesentlich\\
Verfügbarkeit der Verkehrsmittel & irrelevant aufgrund der Notsituation\\
Zur Verfügung stehende Informationen & wesentlich\\
\midrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape Situationsspezifische Einflussgrößen} \\
\addlinespace
Gepäcktransport & wesentlich\\
Fahrradmitnahme & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\
Tageszeit & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\
Jahreszeit & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\
Wetter & als wesentliche Kategorie hinzugefügt\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]